# Translate Special Characters with npm latinize is not working dynamically

Tags: javascript, npm, special-characters

I am using latinize to translate german language's special characters to English, they module work only when I pass string within single or double quotes, but not when I pass by storing them inside a variable.

`import latinize from 'latinize';`

ANd inside render, I console this and it works fine,

```
console.log('render', latinize('VfL Osnabrück'))
```

also when i pass my

```
let tag_name = 'VfL Osnabrück';
console.log('render', latinize('VfL Osnabrück'))
```

it will again works fine, but did not work fine when I get tag_name from my api. And complete code is below

```
let tag_parsing = sub_category_id.split('%20');
let tag_string = '';
for (let i = 0; i < tag_parsing.length; i++) {
    tag_parsing[i];
    // tag_parsing[0] == Vlf
    // tag_parsing[1] == Osnabrück

    console.log('latinized text', tag_parsing[i]);
    tag_string += ' ' + tag_parsing[i]
}
```

**OUTPUT**

output of latinized text ==> Osnabr%C3%BCck

output of latinized text inside quotes ==> Osnabruck

[image][image]
I also try with .toString() but did not work

Comment: Please try to include more details about what isn't working. Is there an error message? What debugging steps have you taken already? What are any steps to reproduce?

Comment: When I simply write         console.log('latized test inside quotes', latinize('Osnabrück'));, I got ==> Osnabruck, that i want, but when I write console.log('latized test inside quotes', latinize(tag_name[0])), I got Osnabr%C3%BCck, it replaces 'ü' with '%C3%BC'

Comment: Since the original string has a space in it and works, have you tried `latinize(full_tag_text)`? Basically without all the string splitting and manipulations? Can you create a small *running* code sandbox with the code you are trying to use that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: Yes, I have tried, and here in sandbox, I cannot create a real scenario, I have commented my line, and you can see here, and in sandbox, I m getting the correct output, because search_params is closed inside quotes,  https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-driscoll-j6xfc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I'm getting my search_params from url, and then I parsed them via this                                                                                         let search_params = this.props.location.search;

Comment: Can you please start chat

Comment: I ran your query string through some basic processing to get the `value` query string value and passed that *entire* sting to `latinize` and it appears to yield the result you expect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231684/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-muhammad-usama-rabani).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font-family that i was using was not contains special german characters, and finally I changed the font-family that supports german special characters, and everything goes smooth and latinize also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be something off with how you are attempting to process the query string from the URL.

Here's a snippet of the logic I used to process your query string in a forked codesandbox. I used a functional component for ease, but the same logic can be used in a class-based component.

```
// get the search string
const { search } = useLocation();

const [latinizedValue, setLatinizedValue] = React.useState("");

React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log({ search });

  // create search params object
  const newParams = new URLSearchParams(search);

  const key = newParams.get("key");
  const value = newParams.get("value")?.trim();

  console.log("Param", key, `"${value}"`);
  console.log("latinize param:", `"${latinize(value)}"`);

  setLatinizedValue(latinize(value));
}, [search]);
```

## Demo

[image: sandbox window with address bar]

[image: Edit translate-special-characters-with-npm-latinize-is-not-working-dynamically]